# Can I exclude certain subfolders from detecting TFS change in TeamCity?

Tags: tfs, teamcity

We have a subfolder in TFS where we check-in the results of the build.  However this is detected as a TFS check-in which then triggers another build in TeamCity.  Is there a way to exclude certain subfolders from triggering a build while still listening to TFS changes on the parent folder?

Comment: Have you checked the following replies? Are they helpful?

Comment: The **NO_CI** comment did sound interesting, not sure yet if I can actually automate that in TeamCity, and if TeamCity will honor it when it retrieves changes from TFS.  I need a TeamCity-specific answer, and I was hoping TeamCity had some way of excluding folders.  TeamCity is using TFS commands and MSBuild to build, yet the answers so far seem focused around the Microsoft devops pipelines solution, hence I have not marked any of them as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the `***NO_CI***` to your check-in comment which will prevent a CI build from starting upon check-in.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the path filters in CI trigger to select the version control paths you want to include and exclude:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths

For example:

[image]